# Embedding from a rational Hamilton quaternion algebra into $M(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: matrices, representation-theory, quaternions

We knew that there are some embeddings as $\mathbb{Q}$-algebras from $H=\{a+bi+cj+dk|a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Q}, i^2=j^2=-1,k=ij=-ji\}$ into $M_2(\mathbb{C})$, for instance:
$a+bi+cj+dk \mapsto \begin{bmatrix} a+bi&c+id\\-c+id&a-ib \end{bmatrix}$

My question:  Is there an embedding into $M(2,\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: I suspect if $K$ is a field in which $-1$ does not have a square root and $H=K[i,j,k]$ the corresponding quaternion algebra, then there is a $K$-algebra embedding $H\to M_2(L)$ for an extension $L/K$ if and only if $L$ contains a square root of $-1$.

Comment: I'm not sure because I can not find a reference for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On dimension grounds, such an embedding would be a bijection, and so an isomorphism. But $H$ and $M(2,\Bbb R)$ aren't isomorphic: the latter has zero-divisors.

There is an embedding into $M(4,\Bbb R)$.

ADDED IN EDIT

I see the question has been edited to make it about the quaternion
algebra over $\Bbb Q$ not over $\Bbb R$.

Actually this makes no difference. The homomorphisms from your new $H$
to a given $\Bbb R$-algebra $A$ correspond to the $\Bbb R$-algebra
homomorphisms from $H\otimes_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb R$ to $A$. Of course
$H\otimes_{\Bbb Q}\Bbb R$ is the classical Hamiltonian quaternions $\Bbb H$.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I had some mistakes. I fixed it

Comment: Having zero divisors is not really a problem if we are talking only for linear mappings: $\mathbb{C}$ is isomorphic as a real linear space to $\mathbb{R}^2$ despite the latter has zero divisors

Comment: In fact, I want to find an embedding $x=a+bi+cj+dk \mapsto h_x \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$ so that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=det(h_x)$.

Comment: @Dynamic det on $M_2(\mathbb R)$ does not give you a positive definite form.

Comment: @Kimball: Could you please explain more for me? I can not see the contradiction.

Comment: @Dynamic You want a linear map from $H$ to $M_2(\mathbb R)$ that sends the (reduced) norm on $H$ to det.  This means it is nonzero on all nonzero elements, hence a linear isomorphism.  But det is not positive on all nonzero elements, where as the norm on $H$ is.

Comment: @Kimball When you say "hence a linear isomorphism," are you referring to the previous version of the problem (where $H$ was an $\Bbb R$-algebra) rather than the current version (where $H$ is a $\Bbb Q$-algebra)? There are $\Bbb Q$-subalgebras of $M_2(\Bbb R)$ of even uncountable dimension (over $\Bbb Q$) on which $\det$ is positive on all but $0$. (Namely, the image of $\Bbb C\to M_2(\Bbb R)$.)

Comment: @arctictern I was referring to the variant where one asks for an $\mathbb R$-linear (rather than algebra) mapping as in user128787's comment.  I didn't realize the question had been edited to a question of $\mathbb Q$-algebras.

Comment: @all: Thank you so much. We need: $1\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}; -1=i^2=j^2=k^2\mapsto \begin{bmatrix}-1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$ and $k=ij=-ji$. After trying some computations, I found that there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to have a short proof of non-existence of an embedding of $H$ (even over $\mathbb Z$) into $M_2(\mathbb R)$. If such an enbedding exists, then its restriction to quaternion group $Q_8$ is a faithful representation of the group. The real faithful reprsentation of $Q_8$ is well-known of having minimal degree 4, not 2. You may easily find this argument on internet.